# Str::is function in laravel How to pass a regular expression

Tags: php, laravel

When I use this to check the "admin/customer/person/1" string in the regular `admin/customer/person/[0-9]+`, the program tells me that the regular expression is correct.

But when I use `Str::is("admin/customer/person/[0-9]+", "admin/customer/person/1")` this function, the result is wrong.

The same thing has the following

```php
Str::is("admin/customer/person/([0-9]+)/edit", "admin/customer/person/1/edit");//result is false
```

```php
Str::is("admin/customer/person/[0-9]+", "admin/customer/person/1");//false
Str::is("admin/customer/person/([0-9]+)", "admin/customer/person/1");//false
Str::is("admin/customer/person/\[0-9]+\\", "admin/customer/person/1");//false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can call `Str::is` with a regex expression string, if you take a look [at the source code for the function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L154),it applies [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on your string before appying [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) so your regular expression will be escaped on purpose. I think it is not intended for your use case, you should directly use a regex and preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

`is` method will not match traditional regular expressions:

```
Str::is('[0-9]', '1');
// false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel 8.0+ helpers it'll look like ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-test)):

```php
Str::of($string)->test($pattern);

// or shorter:
str($string)->test($pattern);
```

For OP's example:

```php
str('admin/customer/person/1/edit')->test('/admin\/customer\/person\/[0-9]+\/edit/');
```